# Loading multiple HTML files(LOCALLY)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I need some help in Loading local HTML files. I have a master table view, Lets say, "1","2","3","4" upto "15" in array named "numbers". i have a detailView to load the HTML files for each elements in array. I use this program:

```
NSString *pathHTML = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"forArray1" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:NO];
NSURL *URLreq = [NSURL fileWithPath:pathHTML];
NSURLRequest *loadURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URLreq];
[webview loadRequest:loadURL];
```

How to create load multiple HTML files for each elements in array ?

NOTE: is it right way of programming by creating 15 nsstring's and load in each switch case in detailVIew???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each row in the master table has an associated number in your `numbers` array. When the row is tapped, you need to navigate to a detail view that will display the HTML file associated with the selected number. Is that right? A simple way to do this is by generating the file name programmatically using `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`:

```
NSNumber *n = numbers[indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"forArray%d", [n integerValue]];
NSString *pathHTML = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"html" inDirectory:NO];
NSURL *URLreq = [NSURL fileWithPath:pathHTML];
NSURLRequest *loadURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URLreq];
[webview loadRequest:loadURL];
```